# How to export bug list (or any custom query) from TFS to Excel from a command line?

Tags: command-line, tfs

I need to export list of bugs from our Team Foundation Server to Excel. It's trivial to do it manually, but I need a command line version since the task needs to be automated.

Anyone knows how to do this?

Comment: Do you want the Excel spreadsheet bound to TFS so that the team ribbon works (and you can publish/refresh etc) or do you just want an export of the data at a particular point in time?

Answer (score 5):

1. To answer your origional question:
   Add a new query in TFS, create your query and click save. This should give you an option to save the query either on the sever or locally. If you chose to save it locally and then change the extension from WIQL to .txt you will have the query available to you :-)
2. I hope you are aware that you have the option of using the 'Team' tag in your Excel/Project ribbon. Having said that, you can create a macro in excel that consumes the refresh or publish button on the team ribbon. Have a look at this sample macro http://blogs.msdn.com/b/teams_wit_tools/archive/2007/03/15/how-to-invoke-tfs-add-in-controls-from-macro-code.aspx

HTH.

Cheers, Tarun

Comment: Hello Tarun. +1 for presenting the option to save as WIQL. I didn't know it & wrote each query by hand :)